# How to remove duplication in properties files in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When developing an application, sometimes you want to support many different configurations, so you use different profiles.

This means that you will have one properties file for each profile, `application-a.properties`, `application-b.properties` and so on.

Now many things in these profiles are the same and some stuffs are different. This leads to a lot of duplication and could lead to problems later on.

Is there a way to remove this properties duplication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to remove this properties duplication?

Put common cross-profile properties in `application.properties` and just profile specific properties into `application-{profile}.properties`. When you enable a specific profile, `application.properties` still will be used but will lower precedence with respect to the profile specific ones. Checkout [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) for more detailed discussion.